# Does Libvirt have any commands to find out disk i/o information?

Tags: linux, python, libvirt, virsh

Disk i/o information like throughput,activity or latency, or at least some disk related data, by which the throughput, activity or latency can be calculated. Is there any virsh command or some method in python-libvirt library, that would help me in finding these value?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `top` like utility `virt-top`, which is used for virtualization stats. You can get network, memory, cpu and block device statisticts of domains.

To install virt-top utility on Debian/Ubutnu use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virt-top
```

For Redhat/Centos use:

```
$ sudo yum install virt-top
```

Start using `virt-top` with:

```
$ virt-top
```

And you'll see something like this:

[image]

If you'd like to save the info from `virt-top` to a file for analyzing you can save it to a `csv` file like this:

```
$ virt-top --csv output.csv
```

Read the manual page `man virt-top` for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not want to use third-party software in my application. I should have been more explicit in my question. Actually, what I require is some virsh command or some method in python-libvirt library, that would help me in finding these values. (Updated question)